# Parallel Plesk - Getting a 404 error on my wordpress homepage

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I am getting Error 404 - Page not found on my Wordpress' homepage. I think the rewrite rules are fine 'cause I can see the other page -http://accuratewatch.com/

But if I directly call the `index.php` file, I will get the desired result - http://accuratewatch.com/index.php

I think the rewrite rules are fine 'cause I can still see the other pages. I even put the redirect rule but it's not working. Here's the copy of my `.htaccess`

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
Redirect / index.php

# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I am using Parrallel Plesk and the site was working with `.asp` before so I override it with `index.php`.
Can you help me figure out the source of the problem?

Comment: Did you used any redirection plugin??

Comment: No. I only installed jigoshop and some jigoshop extensions, WP Better Emails and Theme My Login